# Problems with custom submit in FormBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing my custom FormBuilder, and I don't understand why the output of method below

```
def submit(label = "Save changes", *args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  new_class = options[:class] || "btn btn-small btn-success"
  @template.content_tag(:div, :class => "form-actions left") do
    @template.content_tag(:button, :class => new_class, :name => 'commit', :type => 'submit', :value => label) do
      @template.content_tag(:i, :class => 'icon-arrow-right icon-on-right')
    end
  end
end
```

is:

```
<div class="form-actions left">
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-success" name="commit" type="submit" value="Salvar">
         <i>{:class=&gt;&quot;icon-arrow-right icon-on-right&quot;}
         </i>
    </button>
</div>
```

especially the "i" tag. How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if content_tag gets a block, the block result will be used as content of the tag. Without a block, the second parameter is the content. What you probably want is

```
@template.content_tag(:i, nil, :class => 'icon-arrow-right icon-on-right')
```